# Where are the ebooks for the Doctorate achievement? Is it possible to miss one?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution I've been finding quite a few ebooks. Reading some of them awards me with a "Scholar" popup and grants 200 xp.

I notice that there is an achievement for reading all 29 of them -- is it possible to miss one of the ebooks and be unable to earn the achievement in your playthrough?

Additionally, are there multiple locations for each ebook, or are they all "one-shot" appearances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to get all of the eBooks in a single walk through. Missing out on any of them at any particular stage will make you ineligible for the achievement.

Source:

http://segmentnext.com/2011/08/23/deus-ex-human-revolution-unique-xp-books-location-guide/

> Doctorate is one of the hardest achievements in Deus Ex: Human
> Revolution. You know why ? because it’s a collectible achievement and
> requires you to collect 29 unique XP books that are scattered
> throughout the cities you will visit in Deus Ex: Human Revolution and
> you need to collect all these books in a single playthrough.
>
> **Sarif HQ**
>
> XP E-Book #1 Location. Look for this Unique XP Book on Pritchard’s
> desk in his office.
>
> XP E-Book #2 Location. Search Office 25 that belongs to Mika Pine on
> the second floor, it is on the same floor as Pritchard’s office.
> Again, it can be found on office desk. Hack the door or use the code
> 4145 to get in.
>
> XP E-Book #3 Location. Look for it in office 27, it is right next to
> office 25. You can either hack to get in or use the vent from the
> neighboring office.
>
> **Sarif Manufacturing**
>
> There are two ebook that you can grab here and you have to grab them
> before entering the aircraft. Make sure you rescue all the hostages
> and then speak to the women ‘Josie Thorpe’ and her husband. (Women
> held by Zeke) Her husband will give you this quest to retrieve these
> two ebooks.
>
> XP E-Book #4 Location. You will encounter an automated turret in the
> hall. Go to the room at the end of this hall and you should find in
> under cardboard boxes.
>
> XP E-Book #5 Location. It is lying on the desk in the left corner of
> the room in which encounter Zeke. You should get it before you
> encounter Zeke.
>
> **Detroit City (First Visit)**
>
> There are total 6 ebooks that you can find in Detroit and you can find
> them in any order.
>
> XP E-Book #6 Location. Look for it on the dresser
> in Jensen’s room, by his bed.
>
> XP E-Book #7 Location. In the Detroit City Police Station morgue, look
> for it on the coroner’s desk.
>
> XP E-Book #8 Location. It is on the desk of the weapon dealer –
> Seurat. You can find this XP book on the desk by his bed. You will
> have to break into his apartment using a Window.
>
> XP E-Book #9 Location. First go to the ‘Downtown Apartments’ area. You
> should enter it through a locked gate which you can open by entering
> ’0002′ pass code. On the second floor, there is a level 5 locked door
> which you can either hack or enter code 2356 to enter. Inside it is
> another level 2 door which you can hack or enter code 8221 to enter.
> You will find XP book is lying by the desk, once you are inside.
>
> XP E-Book #10 Location. Take ‘One Good Turn Deserves Another’ side
> quest and enter Greg Thorpe’s apartment. Look for the XP Book on
> cabinet next to his bed.
>
> XP E-Book #11 Location. Look for this XP Book on a barrel inside
> Derelict Row interior area.
>
> **FEMA Camp**
>
> XP E-Book #12 Location. Head south from the detention block in the
> FEMA Camp. You should find a locked room past the canteen on floor 4.
> Ebook is lying on the desk inside.
>
> **Shanghai City**
>
> XP E-Book #13 Location. Look for this XP Book inside The Hive in Bobby
> Bao’s office which is on the first floor. It’s a restricted area so
> you will need to use all your stealth to reach there.
>
> XP E-Book #14 Location. Another XP E-book that you can find in The
> Hive. This time you will need to search Tong’s office that is located
> in the basement. To get inside, you will need to persuade Tong at the
> club bar. Make sure you save the game here since it may require
> multiple attempts.
>
> XP E-Book #15 Location. Before you enter into Van Bruggen’s office,
> take a left of the main entrance and you will come across a locked
> room. You can hack this room to reach a unique XP E-book inside that
> is lying on the kitchen counter. There are two guards on duty here and
> the room is just behind them.
>
> XP E-Book #16 Location. For this XP Book, you need to go to Youzhao
> District. Go to the Downtown Apartments, climb up the rooftop using
> the ladders. You will see a rooftop opening, get inside the building
> on the second floor to the locked room with an NPC working on his
> computer desk. The ebook is on his computer desk.
>
> XP E-Book #17 Location. From the rooftops of Downtown Apartments, head
> north into the apartment. There is a women looking over the walkaway,
> the apartment is beyond where she stands. As you enter this locked
> apartment, you will notice this XP Book.
>
> XP E-Book #18 Location. Finally, search the Alice Gardens Pods area
> for XP Book. Go to the second floor, and look for the pod number 143.
> The ebook is sitting tight on it.
>
> **Lower Tai Yong Medical**
>
> XP E-Book #19 Location. Take yourself to the highest level of the
> Pangu and look for this ebook just before you enter into the elevator.
> You should notice a vent up on the wall – stack the boxes nearby to
> reach the vent and you should find this ebook next to to a dead body.
> He died reading, YEAH!
>
> **Upper Tai Yong Medical**
>
> XP E-Book #20 Location. Once you are in the upper area (TOP), find
> ‘Lee Geng Memorial Laboratory’. You will find the XP book on a low
> cabinet shelf that is lying in the middle of the room.
>
> XP E-Book #21 Location. From Hangar, head to the southwest corner of
> the security room before you make your escape. This XP book is lying
> on a desk inside that room. So make sure you get it before you run
> away.
>
> **Picus**
>
> XP E-Book #22 Location. You will find this XP Book as you escape using
> the elevator. Take the vent next to hand sculpture and drop down to
> head into the room in the corner. There is a desk inside that room and
> the book is lying over it begging you to get her.
>
> XP E-Book #23 Location. Before heading down the basement, enter the
> side room there. You will find this XP Book inside. It’s second floor
> and you can easily spot the book as you enter the room.
>
> **Harvester Hideout**
>
> XP E-Book #24 Location. To get this XP Book, you need to enter the
> lowest level of the Harvester Hideout and enter the autopsy room. It’s
> on a desk.
>
> **Detroit (Second Visit)**
>
> XP E-Book #25 Location. Go to the backstage of the Convention Center.
> You will find the security guards watching TV which makes it easy for
> you to sneak past them and retrieve this ebook lying in the corner of
> this room.
>
> XP E-Book #26 Location. When you confront Sandoval, Search his desk
> for this XP Book.
>
> XP E-Book #27 Location. Go to the LIMB Clinic and go the section of
> clinic where Augmentations are performed. The XP book is lying on a
> stand. Get it!
>
> **Omega Ranch**
>
> XP E-Book #28 Location. Second floor, cold storage room. Look for this
> XP Book next to the elevator.
>
> XP E-Book #29 Location. Once you have defeated Namir, Hack her safe to
> get the last ebook.

Read more: http://segmentnext.com/2011/08/23/deus-ex-human-revolution-unique-xp-books-location-guide/#ixzz1Xg09Yoyu

Answer (score 6):

*Yes* it is possible to miss some. While some of them are located in area's you'll visit more than once, many are located in places you'll never be able to visit again.

One of the most prominent examples is the one when you're climbing through the Pangu on your way to Tai Yong Medical, you're required to have the Icarus Landing system by the time you get there or you won't be able to read the ebook (the fall will kill you).

It's best to look up the locations of all the books and make a new playthrough on the easiest difficulty purely with the intent to find all of the ebooks required for the achievement if you're going for it.

Comment: For exactly this reason, I avoided spending Praxis points until I absolutely had to. It's always good to keep 2-4 points around (or more!) for spending on this kind of thing, at least until you've bought all of the area-access augmentations.

Comment: ...And I *just* finished making my way through the Pangu. I even saw the e-book, but only had 1 praxis point available at the time.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to get there without the Icarus Landing System. I made a video on this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBFg1YjL_t4

Answer (score 3):

Here is another [guide](http://www.msxbox-world.com/xbox360/guides/209/deus-ex-human-revolution/1050/upper-tai-yong-medical.html) to getting all of the XP eBooks. This one has pictures, and also shows where they are on the map.

Note that not all eBooks are needed for this achievement, only those that give you XP. There doesn't seem to be any logic to which ones give XP and which ones don't.

Comment: All the ones that give XP are written by the same guy.

Comment: To add to the above comment, they're all written by Hugh Darrow, the "father" of augmentations.